# ra & dec conversion from hh:mm:ss to degrees

Tags: python, awk

I have a file that contains ra & dec in hh:mm:ss format. 
Say the file name is "coord.txt" and it's content is :

> 06 40 34.8 10 04 22 
>     06 41 11.6 10 02 24 
>     06 40 50.9 10 01 43

06 40 34.8 is the ra and 10 04 22 is the dec
How do I convert it to degrees with python or any other program.

Comment: What do "ra" and "dec" stand for?

Comment: lmgtfy: ra dec to degrees python:
http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/

Comment: @ Scott "ra" stands for right ascension and "dec" stands for declination. Those are coordinates for astronomical objects.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input and at least the pseudo-code for what you want to do. I assume you know the conversion algorithm so do feel free to share with the rest of us.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "06 40 34.8 10 04 22 06 41 11.6 10 02 24 06 40 50.9 10 01 43"
# or s = f.readline()
d = [float(i) for i in s.split()] 
# d = [6.0, 40.0, 34.8, 10.0, 4.0, 22.0, 6.0, 41.0, 11.6, 10.0, 2.0, 24.0, 6.0, 40.0, 50.9, 10.0, 1.0, 43.0]

d2 = [d[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(d), 3)] 
# d2 = [[6.0, 40.0, 34.8], [10.0, 4.0, 22.0], [6.0, 41.0, 11.6], [10.0, 2.0, 24.0], [6.0, 40.0, 50.9], [10.0, 1.0, 43.0]]

d3 = [(s/3600 + m/60 + h) * 15 for h,m,s in d2]

d4 = [d3[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(d3), 2)]

print d4
# [[100.145, 151.09166666666667], [100.29833333333333, 150.6], [100.21208333333334, 150.42916666666667]]
```

Answer (score 0):

implementing @M.Danilchenko's logic in `awk`

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=3) a[++c]=($i*15+($(i+1)+$(i+2)/60)/4);
        for(i=1;i<c;i+=2) printf "(%.3f,%.3f) ", a[i],a[i+1]; 
        print ""}' file

(100.145,151.092) (100.298,150.600) (100.212,150.429)
```

where

```
$ cat file
06 40 34.8 10 04 22 06 41 11.6 10 02 24 06 40 50.9 10 01 43
```